# Upload data into sql table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

this is the code given to me:

```
 protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            divTempForm.Visible = true;
            rptMailTemplate.Visible = false;

            mMailTemplate mail = new mMailTemplate();
            mail.MailTempleteCode = txtMailTempCode.Text;
            mail.Subject = txtMailSubject.Text;
            mail.InsertedBy = _objUserIdentity.UserID;
            mail.Body = hdsummernote.Value;
            mail.MailBodyType = ddlMailBodyType.SelectedValue;
            //mail.Active = lblActive.Text;
            mail.Active = "Y";



            DataSet ds = mtc.InsertMailTemplate(mail);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["out_msg"].ToString() == "RecordAdded")
                {
                    if (fuImg.HasFile)
                    {
                        fuImg.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/MailerImages/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MailTemplateID"] + "_" + fuImg.FileName));

                        **mail.BodyImagePath = @"\MailerImages\" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MailTemplateID"] + "_" + fuImg.FileName;**
                    }
                }
            }
            Response.Redirect("MotivationUI.aspx");
        }
```

Basically what this code does is add the values from textbox into sql server. But i need help at mail.BodyImagePath. The text creates a URL for the location of image stored on the server and i need to store that "URL" into the sql table. Any idea how i should do it?

Comment: So, is your question about how to make database updates or is it how to get the value out of a DataTable? I also cannot see the reason for obtaining a DataSet from a mMailTemplate.

Comment: mMailTemplate contains all the getters and setters

 public class mMailTemplate
    {
        public string MailTemplateID { get; set; }
        public string MailTempleteCode { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Active { get; set; }
        public string InsertedBy { get; set; }
        public string DefaultAttachment { get; set; }
        public string HasIndAttachment { get; set; }
        public string MailBodyType { get; set; }
        public string BodyImagePath { get; set; }
    }

Comment: i want to insert the values stored in mail.BodyImagePath into a column called BodyImagePath in the SQL table

Comment: I was able to recognize that it was a class. What I don't get is why you would obtain a DataSet from a single instance of a class. What does `InsertMailTemplate` do? and, again what **exactly** is the problem you are having?

Comment: There should be an application at the email receive address that should automatically save the data into the database. Are you suppose to write that application?

Comment: OK, I think I'm starting to understand. You found an example where a DataSet is used to update a database and that is the basis for your plan. Assuming you are using Microsoft SQL Server, do research on SqlCommand, SqlParameter and ExecuteNonQuery. You don't need a DataSet to insert one row unless maybe you are doing some data-binding in a user interface.

Comment: True, but I often use a data row, since then I don't have to write a whole bunch of paramters - you can update the one row with strong type checking, and then with one simple command do a MyDataAdapter.Update(myTable). That simple one line statement is 100x easier to write then a whole sql udpate statement with 20+ parameters. So yes, I do this all the time to save world poverty and having to write out 20+ parameters to update a simple row of data as opposed to using .Update method of a data adaptor with one line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the image path in string variable within the if condition and update it using your sql query:

```
string path = @"\MailerImages\" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MailTemplateID"] + "_" + fuImg.FileName;

Update table set columnName = path where //your condition here;
```

Note: Do that before `Response.Redirect("MotivationUI.aspx");` or within your if condition after assigning path to variable.